# How do I get my menu back after using .toggle?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

A button link is used to .toggle a menu when I resize to a smaller window (responsive design).

I can use the button to toggle the menu but how do I get the menu to come back after resizing to a bigger window (Example: I tilt my tablet/ mobile to landscape)?

http://jsfiddle.net/uzDP2/6/ (drag the window to resize)

HTML:

```
<img class="mobileicon" src="http://i.imgur.com/M7AiJ0P.png" width="40" height="29" alt="Mobile icon" />
<div class="menuframe">
    <a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#">Products and Services</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#">Other Link</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#">Image Gallery</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#">Links</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<div class="menuframe"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.mobileicon {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .mobileicon {
        display: block
    }    
    .menuframe {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector(".mobileicon").addEventListener("click", function(){
    $(".menuframe").toggle();
    });
```

Comment: CmdrTchort's answer helped me get it right. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/uzDP2/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.toggle()` will add an inline css to the element and that will override the css of the class. I suggest you use `.toggleClass()` for this problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/b_m_h/uzDP2/9/

jQuery:

```
document.querySelector(".mobileicon").addEventListener("click", function(){
    $(".menuframe").toggleClass('visible');
});
```

CSS:

```
.mobileicon {
    display: none;
}
.menuframe {
    display: block;
}
.visible{
    display: block !important;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .mobileicon {
        display: block
    }    
    .menuframe {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this better than CmdrTchort's answer and am happily using it. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

Add this to your CSS to add a display for your frame again:

```
@media (min-width: 400px){

    .menuframe{
        display:block;    
    }

}
```

You can also add a jQuery listener for the event-changed, to fire for a specific width:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 400){
        $(".menuframe").show();        
    }
});
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks man, it would have taken me days to figure that out. Got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work on window resizing whit some checking.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(IwantToToggle){
        //toggle menu
    }
});
```